# Inequality with logs

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math

Let $n>1$ be a integer, show that there exists a constant $t$ such that

$$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4(n)\rfloor}\lfloor \frac{n+2^{2j}}{2^{2j+1}}\rfloor-\frac{4n}{9}\le t\log_{10} n .$$

Answer (score 1):

As $[x]+1>x$, if $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{j=0}^k ( [\frac{n-2^j}{2^{2j+1}}]+1)$  we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}(\frac{n-2^j}{2^{2j+1}})=\frac{n}{2}\frac{4-4^{-k}}{3}-\frac{2-2^{-k}}{2}\leq S_n \leq  \frac{4n}{9}+t\log_{10}(n)$$
Now divide by $n$, and $n\to +\infty$, one gets $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}\leq \frac{4}{9}$, a contradiction. So it seems that your constant does not exists  (if my computations are correct)